# Connection time out while reading JSON from URL

Tags: java, json, getjson

I am running below program to fetch JSON string from URL.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;

public class Temp {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(readUrl("http://ip-api.com/json/31.15.112.160"));
    }

    private static String readUrl(String urlString) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            int read;
            char[] chars = new char[1024];
            while ((read = reader.read(chars)) != -1)
                buffer.append(chars, 0, read); 

            return buffer.toString();
        } finally {
            if (reader != null)
                reader.close();
        }
    }
}
```

And its resulting in

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
```

However if I try to access the URL directly from browser, it doesn't throw any issue.

And below jQuery call works fine too.

```
$.getJSON("http://ip-api.com/json/31.15.112.160",
        function(data){
            document.getElementById("jsonIpDataISP").value = data.isp;
            document.getElementById("jsonIpDataCity").value = data.city;
            document.getElementById("jsonIpDataCountry").value = data.country;
            document.getElementById("jsonIpDataOrg").value = data.org;
            document.getElementById("jsonIpDataTimeZone").value = data.timezone;

            alert(data.isp);
            alert(data.city);
            alert(data.country);
            alert(data.org);
            alert(data.timezone);
      });
```

This was actually working fine when I tried yesterday but somehow it's causing exception now.
Will really appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 0):

My antivirus was preventing the access. I have disabled it and seeing no issues now.